# Publish multiple WCF Service Application to one IIS virtual application

Tags: c#, wcf

In our project we have 11 WCF Service Application on IIS.
Each Service Application own its virtual application.

I want to publish all Service Application's to one virtual application on IIS.
So what is the best solution for that problem.

My solution is I'll add post build events to each service application and I'll copy .svc files and assemblies to one folder.And I will create virtual application for this folder.

Any other ideas??